# Subtotal in result row returns 0 in excel table

Tags: excel, subtotal, excel-tables

I have an excel table ("lstTestSource") like this:

[image]

I have a second excel table ("lstTestResult"), which evaluates the first one:

[image]

There is a formula in each row in the second column ("lstTestResult"):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((lstTestSource[Color]=[@Color])*(SUBTOTAL(109; OFFSET(lstTestSource[[#Kopfzeilen];[Amount]]; ROW(lstTestSource[Amount])-ROW(lstTestSource[#Kopfzeilen]); 0))))
```

The formula works fine, I can filter "lstTestSource" and the result in the rows will show the right numbers.

At the end of "lstTestResult" is a result row, where the result is always 0, regardless of the current filter in "lstTestResult". I would like to use the SUBTOTAL function there too.

Automatic calculation is turned on.

I've tried to google this problem but I couldn't find any hint to solve this issue. I would appreciate every help! Thanks!